# Focal Point - Changes don't take effect when Saved a second, or third time

Tags: plugins, craft3

When I set the Focal Point for the first time, it works. If I change the Focal Point and save again, the changes do not take effect.

Now, if I set the Focal Point and "save as a new asset", I can use that new file and its Focal Point. But, if I change that Focal Point, I have to "save as a new asset", which creates multiple copies of the same image.

I'm also using ImageOptimize plugin. Any ideas why my Focal Point changes don't take effect?

Comment: This is most likely a bug, you should rather open an issue on https://github.com/craftcms/cms

Comment: If you're using Chrome, make sure you open up the URL to the image itself (you can do this by clicking on the variant in the OptimizedImages field) and do a Shift-reload. Chrome will locally cache images so you won't see the changes unless you force it to reload the image from the source.

Comment: @khalwat I tried that technique, but now I'm thinking the plugin I'm using has a lock on the image, and is not including the focal point change, once I re-save that image...

Comment: @carlcs Turns out this was a bug in Craft 3, which in turn affected the plugin ImageOptimize. The bug has now been addressed and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, make sure you open up the URL to the image itself (you can do this by clicking on the variant in the OptimizedImages field) and do a Shift-reload. Chrome will locally cache images so you won't see the changes unless you force it to reload the image from the source.

Comment: I'm using a square crop call, instead of the standard call the plugin asks for. Could this be affecting the Focal Point?

`<img 
alt="{{ article.title }}"
src="{{ image.optimizedImages.optimizedImageUrls[300] }}" 
sizes="300px" />`

Comment: Additionally, when I look at the URL, I see `center_center` as part of the crop...
`site.com/uploads/_150x150_crop_center-center_60_line/image-file.jpg`

Comment: So the `150x150` is the size of the image, `crop` is the type of cropping being done, `center-center` means the Focal Point either hasn't been set for some reason. `60` is the image quality, and `line` is the fact that it's an interlaced image.